# Why cant i change a subclass value

Tags: java, subclass

SO,letsay we have a bicycle superclass with cadence 0 and 3 subclasses.I want the "trotineta" sbuclass to have cadence 5 while the other 2 subclasses cadence remains 0.
Why isnt this working?

```
    class Trotineta extends Bicycle{   
        Bicycle.cadence = 5;
    }
```

Comment: What is `Bicycle.cadence`?

Comment: Bicycle is the superclass while cadence is it`s field.

Comment: And how is this field defined? Is it `static`?

Comment: cadence is static meaning no instance of object is needed for it to exist / be initialized. once you change it, it will change it's value for all instances of bicycles

Comment: class Bicycle{
int cadence = 0;
}

Comment: @GeorgeMarin: if you say "class Bicycle{ int cadence = 0; }" is your Bicycle class then the code in the question doesn't make sense. Read again MihaiC's comment.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't shown the definition of `Bicycle.cadence`, but based on the syntax, I'm assuming it's a static member. If you change a static member of the base class, all instances of all sub-classes will be affected by this change, since a static member has a single value for all instances of the class.

Now, if `cadence` wouldn't be static, you can give it a different value in the constructor of `Trotineta` (assuming the sub-class has access to that member).

```
public Trotineta ()
{
    cadence = 5;
}
```

This would be somewhat wasteful, though, since each instance of `Bicycle` would have its own `cadence` member.

Comment: 'public class Bicycle{ int cadence = 0; }
class Trotineta extends Bicycle{   
        Bicycle.cadence = 5;
    }'

Comment: @GeorgeMarin `Bicycle.cadence` is the syntax used to access static members. If cadence is not static, that syntax won't work.

Comment: @GeorgeMarin And assigning a value to a member as in `Bicycle.cadence = 5;` must be either in a method or in an initialization block.

Answer (score 1):

You can create getter and setter or just use word `super`

```
public class TestONE extends TestTWO {
    {
        super.gg = 4;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.err.println(new TestONE().gg);
    }
}
class TestTWO {
    static int gg = 0;
}
```

or

```
public class TestONE extends TestTWO {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            TestONE.setGg(5);
            System.err.println(new TestTWO().gg);
        }
    }
class TestTWO {
        protected static int gg = 0;

        public static int getGg() {
            return gg;
        }

        public static void setGg(int gg) {
            TestTWO.gg = gg;
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    class Bicycle{ 
                  int cadence = 0;
                  /* since no access modifier is mentioned, by default cadence becomes 
                  package private ie; it cannot be accessed outside the package 
                  in which it is defined now*/  
                 }

    class Trotineta extends Bicycle{
                                    Bicycle.cadence = 5; 
                                    /* you cannot do this as cadence is not a static 
                                    attribute of class Bicycle*/
                                    }
```

// Below is one of the possible solutions

```
   class Trotineta extends Bicycle{
             /*below code can also be written in a method but not outside as you have
               written in your example code*/
                                    { 
                                     this.cadence = 5; 
                                    //here 'this' is the current instance of Trotineta 
                                    } 
                                  }
```

Comment: Looks like you've answered again rather than editing your first answer